# Multi level grouping in mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am trying to group the following data in mongodb first by dates then by Task_type and get total duration. I am trying to achieve it by using $group aggregation and $sum, but I am only getting sum of duration of particular date. I need it one step further by separating Task_type

```
{
    "name" : "Employee1",
    "Mail" : "Employee1@flipr.com",
    "Contact" : 1111111111,
    "Department" : "Operations",
    "Joining_Date" : "2022-02-02",
    "Password" : "Employee1",
    "Work" : 
    [
        {
            "date" : "2022-10-07",
            "Tasks" : {"Task_description" : "Worked on project","Task_type" : "Work","Start_time" : "09:20:00","duration" : 20}
                       
        },
        {
            "date" : "2022-10-07",
            "Tasks" : {"Task_description" : "Attended daily meeting","Task_type" : "Meeting","Start_time" : "10:30:00","duration" : 60}
        },
        {
            "date" : "2022-10-06",
            "Tasks" : {"Task_description" : "Lunch break","Task_type" : "Break","Start_time" : "13:00:00","duration" : 50}
        },
        {
            "date" : "2022-10-06",
            "Tasks" : {"Task_description" : "Tea Break","Task_type" : "Break","Start_time" : "17:30:00","duration" : 10}
        },
        {
            "date" : "2022-10-08",
            "Tasks" : {"Task_description" : "Meeting with partners","Task_type" : "Meeting","Start_time" : "13:00:00","duration" : 50}
        }
        
    ]
    
}
```

My desired output is:

```
{_id:'2022-10-07', WorkDuration:20, MeetingDuration:60, BreakDuration:0},
{_id:'2022-10-06', WorkDuration:0, MeetingDuration:0, BreakDuration:60},
{_id:'2022-10-08', WorkDuration:0, MeetingDuration:50, BreakDuration:0}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the mongoplayground.net example of what you are currently trying? Sounds like you may need `_id: { field1: '$fieldName1', field2: '$fieldName2' }, <accumulators>`

Comment: @user20042973 I don't have playground. I am new to Mongodb and using shell.

Comment: I will share the query - https://pastebin.com/GtYKEYUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to `$group` twice. First by both `Task_type` and `date`, and then only by `date`, summing up the duration according to each `Task_type`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$Work"},
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: "$Work.date",
      Task_type: "$Work.Tasks.Task_type",
      duration: "$Work.Tasks.duration"
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: {Task_type: "$Task_type", "date": "$date"},
      duration: {$sum: "$duration"}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.date",
      WorkDuration: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.Task_type", "Work"]}, "$duration", 0]}},
      MeetingDuration: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.Task_type", "Meeting"]}, "$duration", 0]}},
      BreakDuration: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$_id.Task_type", "Break"]}, "$duration", 0]}}
  }},
  {$sort: {_id: 1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SYCrB_PVEyC)

Comment: I didn't know we can use condition on a field and add another field. Thank you